# Prevent JIRA from clobbering FireFox's forward-slash (in page) search?

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, jira

JIRA includes the misfeature of co-opting the shortcut key `/` and uses it to place focus in its top-right 'Quick Search' input field.  Normally in FireFox `/` brings up a FireFox 'in page' search for quickly finding text on the current page.  This is *really* annoying.

Is there a way to prevent JIRA clobbering the normal FireFox `/` behaviour?

There is a menu option in 'Keyboard Shortcuts' which brings up a dialog showing all the JIRA shortcut keys.  And there is an option at the bottom: 'Disable Keyboard Shortcuts'.  Unfortunately disabling them then makes `/` do nothing at all; it does not restore the normal FireFox behaviour.

I already know about the `'` search shortcut key in FireFox.  But as this searches links only it doesn't really help most of the time.

Comment: I would sure love to find a fix for this, too. Not for JIRA in particular, but in the general case. Other sites that do this – npmjs.com, twitter.com, etc. – drive me up the wall. Unfortunately I haven't found anything other than tips like [these workarounds](http://superuser.com/questions/113806/firefox-dont-allow-websites-to-override-the-slash-key), which aren't sufficient for me.

Comment: MikeFHays comment at superuser (your 'these workarounds' link) is worth repeating: "Other examples: Twitter, Facebook (Messages), Rally. It's so absurd to me, because the only way anyone will discover this "feature" is by trying to use / for its usual purpose! The only people who are affected by this are the ones who are frustrated by it!"  That sums it up exactly.

Comment: also happens on GitHub.